# How do I show multiple value/field from a foreign key?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Okay so I don't know how to word my question, so excuse me if it doesn't make sense

My view

```
@forelse ($transaction as $key=>$value)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{$key + 1}}</td
        <td>{{ $value->transaction_item->item->item_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->transaction_item->quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->transaction_item->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->total_price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->updated_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->last_updated_by }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

My controller

```
$transaction = Transaction::all();
return view('transaction.index', compact('transaction'));
```

My model

```
    // Transaction
    protected $table = 'transaction';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function transaction_item()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TransactionItem::class, 'transaction_id');
    }
```

```
    // TransactionItem
    protected $table = 'transaction_item';
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id');
    }
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MasterItem::class, 'master_item_id');
    }
```

`Transaction` has `TransactionItem` that has multiple `item`, `quantity`, and `price`. How do I show that to my blade view? When I just do `{{$value->transaction_item->item->item_name}}`, it only show the first `item` and also the same for `quantity` and `price`. I tried changing `item` relationship in my `TransactionItem` to `belongsToMany` but then this error popped up

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myDatabase.master_item_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `master_item`.*, `master_item_id`.`transaction_item_id` as `pivot_transaction_item_id`, `master_item_id`.`master_item_id` as `pivot_master_item_id` from `master_item` inner join `master_item_id` on `master_item`.`id` = `master_item_id`.`master_item_id` where `master_item_id`.`transaction_item_id` = 3)
```

I'm not sure what causes that problem but, I dont have table or column named `transaction_item_id` that's for sure, my table `transaction_item` primary key is `id`

Here's my table structure

```
transaction: id(pk), total_price
transaction_item: id(pk), transaction_id(fk), master_item_id(fk), quantity, price
master_item: id(pk), item_name, price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell us about your tables structure first , table names , foreign keys and how they are related ... something doesn't add up

you said TransactionItem that has multiple items , but in your relation you have TransactionItem  belongs to items

also in `belongsToMany` second argument is the table name not the foreign key

so if you have this table structure

```
transactions : id , total_price
items : id , item_name , item_price 
transaction_items : id ,transaction_id , item_id
```

in this scenario `transaction_items` is a pivot table you can search and read about it
basically it only connects 2 table together

you dont need to add relation to pivot table model , you can directly define relation between 2 tables (transactions , items ) just by mentioning their pivot table
your relation should be

```
// Transaction

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( Item::class, 'transaction_items' , 'transaction_id' , 'item_id' );
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($transactions as $key=>$transaction)

   {{$transaction->total_price}}

   @foreach($transaction->items as $item )
     {{$item->item_name}}
   @endforeach
                         
@endforeach
```

------------------------------ edit-----------------------

usually pivot table only contains the `id` of other 2 other table so it doesn't have any useful data in it  , it only works as a bridge between `transactions` and `items`

```
transaction -> transaction_item -> items
```

scenario happens in many to many relation (if its `1 to many` or `1 to 1` relation you can just store the `id`of table 1 directly in other table 2 )

so when you define `belongsToMany` relation you directly connect 2 main tables together and mention the name of pivot table basically it goes like

`transaction belongs to many items via transaction_item`

```
// Transaction

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( Item::class, 'transaction_items' );
}
```

but you have stored other data apart from foreign keys (id) in the `transaction_item`  table so this wont work for you ... you need direct relation to `transaction_item`  if you want to show `quantity, price`

so in your case u should define

```
// Transaction

public function transaction_item()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TransactionItem::class, 'transaction_id');
}


// TransactionItem

public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TransactionItem::class, 'item_id');
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($transactions as $key=>$transaction)

   {{$transaction->total_price}}

   @foreach($transaction->transaction_item $transaction_item)
     {{$transaction_item->price}}
     {{$transaction_item->quantity}}
     {{$transaction_item->item->item_name}}
   @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I added my table structure, can you look again to my problem? Thanks! I tried your relation code and add it to my `Transaction` model and it work, but why that relation is in `Transaction`? And not in my `TransactionItem`? Oh and in view the `@foreach` is worked but for only the `item_name`. When I tried `@foreach` again the `quantity` and `price`, it popped up error `foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given`. When I `@foreach` all of them at once it just, I don't know, not an error but it messed up my table. Can you tell me how to show this `item` properly to my blade?

Comment: Nevermind, `foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given` I fixed this by changing `as` variable name in the foreach. But now for some reason my `quantity` didn't show up at all. But for the `item_name` and for my `price` showing up just fine, I don't know what cause this, I'll attach my updated view in my post

Comment: Fixed. I forgot to edit my relation `transaction_item` on my `Transaction` model from `hasOne` to `hasMany`

Comment: @SomeRandomCode i've edited my answer read the edit part at the bottom